# How to succesfully create a bootable Windows installation USB stick on Mac?

Tags: bootcamp

This should be a trivial one; unfortunately, it isn't. I've been trying to create a bootable USB stick for Windows 10. The bootcamp tool seems easy to use, but it always stops with the following message:

```
Your bootable USB drive could not be created.
There is not enough space available on the disk.
```

I've tried with too different USB sticks, a KINGSTON USB 2.0 16Gb stick and a Corsair USB 3.0 32Gb stick. I first tried to do this on MacOS 10.12, no luck, and then took this experience as an incentive to upgrade to MacOS 10.14, yielding the same result.

The Windows version I downloaded from Microsoft is the newest October update. The filename is:

```
Win10_1809Oct_EnglishInternational_x64.iso
```

The bootcamp tool doesn't allow any customization of the process, I don't think there is anything I could do different. I have difficulties to believe that bootcamp is just broken.

I've also tried to create the USB stick both with dd and Etcher, both yielding no error, but the stick wasn't bootable in the end. Etcher even warned me about this and suggested to use bootcamp instead. Instructions how to make the USB stick bootable would be welcome.

Comment: Will this be used to install Windows on a Mac? If so, which model Mac?

Comment: Yes, a MacBook Air 2014

Comment: What if you reformat it as exFAT or some such? I know Boot Camp does reformat the thumb drive as it sets it up for a Windows install but it's a quick step. Also do you have an 8GB stick to try?

Comment: @Steve Chambers: The Boot Camp Utility formats the USB flash drive as FAT32. However, there is one file that needs to be copied from the ISO to the USB flash drive that is over the 4 GB limit. If you mount the ISO, you find that `/sources/install.wim` is 4.4 GB in size.

Comment: Ok, i haven’t noticed that. That explains the error. So bootcamp is indeed just broken then?

Comment: Well, does Microsoft still allow you to download the previous version of the iso? I believe the 1803 version (1803 = 2018 March) has a `install.wim` of 4.09 GB which I believe will fit.

Comment: There is the April version. I’m downloading it now.

Comment: I just checked the March version by coping to a FAT32 volume. The file fits.

Comment: You can install the 1809 version from a flash drive. However, you can not use the Boot Camp Assistant to create the flash drive. Also, you can not use the Widows Installer Graphical Interface either. In other words, you have to install Windows by using both the macOS and Windows command line interface (CLI).  If you wish, I could provide the steps. However, there are quite a few steps.

Comment: If the April version works, please post a comment or post your own answer.

Comment: The April Version did work.

Comment: I did post an answer to your question. See [Boot Camp Assistant fails to create the USB installer from the Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://superuser.com/questions/1385264/boot-camp-assistant-fails-to-create-the-usb-installer-from-the-windows-10-octobe). I would post the answer here, but I know the people running AD do not like duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

I found a guy who told a work around how to create, in the "right way", a USB bootable for both (on bootcamp and windows machine). The "Answer 1" works for me. I hope it helps you too.

[Boot Camp Assistant fails to create the USB installer from the Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://superuser.com/questions/1385264/boot-camp-assistant-fails-to-create-the-usb-installer-from-the-windows-10-octobe)

See ya!